# why jquery .index() returns -1? I am applying it on a unordred list and it is returning only -1 for all elements

Tags: jquery, list, indexing, unordered

```
<ul id="Item_list">
<li class='list1'>........</li>
<li class='list2'>........</li>
<li class='list3'>........</li>
<li class='list4'>........</li>
<li class='list5'>........</li>
</ul>
```

I am using

```
$("#Item_list li").click(function(){
alert($(this).index())});
```

to get the index but it is returning only -1

Comment: No it's not -->  http://jsfiddle.net/x6u24/ ??

Comment: Spec says that `If the element is not found, .index() will return -1.` http://api.jquery.com/index/

Comment: I rechecked thet the element exits..If there can be other reasons for this?

Comment: The fiddle clearly indicates otherwise. Do you get `-1` on the fiddle as well? If so, what is your setup (OS/browser)? If not, can you create a reproducible case (e.g, a jsFiddle that demonstrates the issue)?